# Use of '-s (third party singular form)' in subjunctive mood

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Example of subjunctive mood. It's used to express commands or demands:

> She demanded that he **leave** the hospital premises … [Salem News]

It’s used to express suggestions.

> I suggest that he **implement** a budget cut in March. [Daily Gleaner]

Why are there no 's' after *leave* and *implement* when the subjects are third persons (he)? Is it because of the 'that' followed by the third persons?

Answer (score 1):

The present subjunctive is identical to the *bare infinitive* form of the verb in *all persons*, *including the third person singular* **(no final -s)**.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's simply how this subjunctive is formed - no other reason. It's a different verb form from the indicative, though very similar.

Note also e.g. "she asked that he *be* ready early tomorrow" - with *be*, this is noticeable in all persons. Also notice the subjunctives *do*, *have* and (archaic) *wit*.

Comment: It's not just how those subjunctive are formed: it's how **all** present subjunctives are formed. The present subjunctive is always identical with the basic form (i.e., the infinitive/imperative) in all persons.

Comment: Right; by "_this_ subjunctive" I meant present subjunctive, not this verb's subjunctive :). Should've been clearer.